# Where are the "real" places from Broken Sword in Paris?

Tags: broken-sword

According to [some](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100909182928AAHC5I3) [people](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070330003802AA1kiTS), the locations in "Broken Sword: The Shadow Of The Templars" (Cafe de la Chandelle Verte, Montfaucon, etc) are based on real places in Paris.

So, where are them exactly?

Comment: I don't think Yahoo Answers can really count as an authoritive source of information.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems that there is no easy way to find out which are the real places as most of the names have been changed i can at least confirm that the places are real more so than yahoo answers.

> “The emails we get show that people actually really enjoy the
>   authenticity. So often I’ve asked about which locations are real,
>   which ones can people visit...it’s just fantastic because at the time
>   you wouldn’t have thought that it actually made any difference, nobody
>   would really care, but it’s great when you’re able to talk to people
>   about these real places and people go to Paris and they go and
>   explore, try and find what’s real and not real.”

Was taken from an interview with the maker of the game found on this site [Source](http://www.redbull.co.uk/cs/Satellite/en_UK/Article/How-Broken-Sword-Beat-Dan-Brown-To-The-Da-Vinci-Code-021243320021783)

Comment: I will also do some research later to try and figure out some of the places for you but its going to boil down to searching each name and hoping that the maker didn;t change it as i expect that most results will be for the game and not the place